# Darksiders 2 freezing

Tags: ps3, darksiders-2

I'm having a real bad time with Darksiders 2, almost at the beginning of the game, after the fight with the ice boss, there's a room when you have to enter. And is freezing there a lot, exact same place. Any ideas? 4 times freezing in the same place, the disc is fine and I erased the update just in case but nothing. Same thing happens.

Comment: Can you install games from disk on a ps3? I've never owned one, but I would try that if possible.

Comment: @TimmyJim No, you can't. Some games do install on the ps3 but is mandatory when it does.

Comment: So after reading some forums about this, it seems like Darksiders 2 has a _ton_ of freezing issues. The solution to those freezes seems to be to decrease SFX, music, and voiceover volume to zero before entering the problematic area. Apparently lowering the gamma setting also could potentially help. Once past the problematic area, it sounds like you can turn those settings back up. Let me know if that works for you!

Comment: @pushasha it didn't work. :(

Comment: Aw, okay. It was worth a try.

Comment: @Ben No. I just pass trought a door and that's it, it freezes.

Comment: Hmm.. okay. Try this: before going through the door, press start and open the settings menu. Change any one option to force a save, then close the menu, and try again. This may be similar to Pushasha's suggestion, but the key to this solution is forcing an auto-save before proceeding

Comment: Alternatively, try re-loading the area (leaving and then re-entering).

Comment: @Ben Try all that and nothing. :(

Comment: Bugger. the only other thing I can suggest is while you say the quality of the disc itself is fine, check the [inner rim](http://www.psdevwiki.com/ps4/images/thumb/e/ed/Blu-Ray_Disc_PS3_GAME_IFPI-_Mastering_SID_Codes_single_layer.png/200px-Blu-Ray_Disc_PS3_GAME_IFPI-_Mastering_SID_Codes_single_layer.png). This ring should have holographic PS symbols and/or "Playstation 3" around it. This is used to identify it's legitimacy, and if this is damaged in any way, may cause issues with the performance. Check it against other game discs to see if this might be the case.

Comment: @Ben That's the weird thing. My brother did finish the game like a month ago, with the same disc, I erased the data, the updates, install again, and nothing, keep happening. I don't know what else to do, to be honest haha.

Comment: Is it the same ps3? I've had similar issues (with other games) where a disc works in my machine, but not in another. The only other thing I can suggest is remove the updates and see what happens (you'll have to play iffline to avoid the updates)

Comment: @Ben Yep, same PS3. The only thing that is a bit different is that he played the game in Spanish and I'm playing on english.

Comment: @Ben I did it!!! Playing offline was the key. Thanks for the help, man.

Answer (score 1):

So, I tried almost everything, download updates, changing settings, but, at the end, the only thing that did work was playing offline (erasing all dlc's). So, yeah, play offline! it should work now.